# Can you replace ints in int Arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, integer

I'm looking for a way to replace every int that is greater than 9 in an array with the sum of the digits. I'm gonna demonstrate an example below.

I have this array:

```
int[] ints2 = new int[] { ints[0] * 2, ints[1], ints[2] * 2, ints[3], ints[4] * 2, ints[5], ints[6] * 2, ints[7], ints[8] * 2, ints[9]};
```

And I want to replace the first int to whatever the sum is of the two digits.
Lets say ints[0] = 9. And ints[0]*2 = 18. The sum should be 1+8 = 9.

Can I use some kind of replace method for ints? Or do you guys have any better ideas of how to deal with this issue?

I tried it like this, but obviously I'm wrong:

```
foreach (int number in ints)
            {
                int newNumberInt;
                
                if (number > 9)
                {
                    string newNum = number.ToString();
                    char[] charNum = newNum.ToCharArray();
                    int[] intNum = Array.ConvertAll(charNum, n => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n));
                    newNumberInt = intNum[0] + intNum[1];                   
                }
                
                newNumberInt = number;
                 
            }
```

Comment: You should take smaller steps. Write a function that takes an int and returns the sum of it's digits as int. *Then test it until it works.*. Then Take an array and replace specific numbers with zero. *Test it until it works*. then switch the replace with zero part with your previously tested function. *Test that until it works*. You are trying to take bites that are too large for you right now. Smaller steps.

Comment: What does `ints2` have to do with anything? it is not used in your code

Comment: ints2 is supposed to be just ints, it’s there because of a test i ran!

Comment: What happens if you have 999? Should it become 27 and then 9?

Comment: What do you want to do about negative numbers ? -999; how does it end up?

Comment: @Anton please do not forget to upvote and select an answer

Comment: @Nigel Bess I have to little reputation to vote! How do I so then?

Comment: @Anton you should now be able to upvote

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Your mistakes are an incorrect addition of digits, and failure to replace the values in the array. Here is a one line method that adds all the digits in an integer (using `System.Linq`):

```
    //Adds up all the digits in a number
    private static int AddDigits(int number) => number.ToString().Sum(digitCharacter => int.Parse(digitCharacter.ToString()));
```

For replacing the values, a `foreach` loop directly on the array won't work, due to changing the contents of the array during enumeration. A simple solution is to use a `for` loop.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length; i++)
        {
            var value = ints[i];
            ints[i] = value > 9 ? AddDigits(value) : value;
        }
```

Note: the `AddDigits` function I wrote only works for positive integers

Comment: No need to string and parse the char, just take `0` off it. `"72".Sum(c => c - '0')`

Comment: @CaiusJard clever. But I would rather throw an exception than return some weird number when the integer was negative